# Access dynamically loaded html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am Trying to load some html in my document with ajax.
The loading is working just file, what i am not able to do is access the loaded html with jquery selectors.

Here is the script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
          url: 'header.html',
          dataType: 'html',
          success: function(data) {
            $("#header").html(data);
    });
});
```

Html :

```
   <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header">
      </div><!--header end-->
    </div>
   </body>
```

I am trying to access html elements like this :

```
$('#bigmenu').hide();
$('#mydiv').mouseenter(function(e){
    $('#bigmenu').fadeIn(100);
});
```

`#bigmenu` and `#mydiv` are elements of dynamically loaded html

However it works if i try to access them inside ajax `success` function.

My question is - How can i access them outside of success function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is `async` call and the success event will be first after your function finishes execution. If you access the element before success function is called then it wont be available. This is why dynamically add element on success '#bigmenu' wont be available to hide before success. And hiding element which is not being rendered would fail, so execute hide function after adding to dom in success. Similaly you need to use `on` to register event for dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).mouseenter('mouseenter','#mydiv', function(e){
    $('#bigmenu').hide();
    $('#bigmenu').fadeIn(100);
});
```

Comment: IS writing this $('#bigmenu').hide();  inside success function the only way ???

Comment: No, any time after success as you add in success.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '#mydiv', function(e){
    $('#bigmenu').hide().fadeIn(100);
});
```

You have to delegate that event to your dynamically loaded HTML element. You have to hide() the div to in order to play an animation on it.

Comment: what about hiding something ??

Answer (score 0):

With dynamically loaded elements which have changed the DOM, you need to use the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$('#bigmenu').hide();

$('#mydiv').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#bigmenu').fadeIn(100);
});
```

You don't have to do this about `hide()` - you only have to use `on()` with functionality centered around [JavaScript events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp).

Comment: $('#bigmenu').hide();  this does not work..

Comment: Have you given your element an ID of 'bigmenu'? Do you want to hide it on pageload?

Comment: yes bigmenu is an ID and i want to hide that

Comment: Are you putting my code into `$(document).ready(function(){ });`?